# Julia expression with equality operator does not work

Tags: julia, expression, eval, metaprogramming

The following code works as intended:

```
x = 1
exp = Expr(:(=), :x, 4)   # :(x = 4)
eval(exp)                 # x is now equal to 4 as expected
```

The following code fails:

```
x = 1
exp = Expr(:(==), :x, 4)  # Got :($(Expr(:(==), :x, 4))) instead of the expected :(x == 4)
eval(exp)                 # ERROR: syntax: invalid syntax (== (outerref x) 4)
```

Answer (score 4):

`==` is a function, so you have:

```
julia> dump(:(x==4))
Expr
  head: Symbol call
  args: Array{Any}((3,))
    1: Symbol ==
    2: Symbol x
    3: Int64 4
```

but

```
julia> dump(:(x=4))
Expr
  head: Symbol =
  args: Array{Any}((2,))
    1: Symbol x
    2: Int64 4
```

so in particular the following works:

```
julia> x = 1
1

julia> exp = Expr(:call, :(==), :x, 4)
:(x == 4)

julia> dump(exp)
Expr
  head: Symbol call
  args: Array{Any}((3,))
    1: Symbol ==
    2: Symbol x
    3: Int64 4

julia> eval(exp)
false
```